# How to keep information from reseting

Tags: objective-c

I have a check box type application, kinda like notes on the iPhone. When the user closes the application and double tabs the home button and deletes the application from the background, the things they have typed also get deleted or reset. I was thinking of calling 
 [self saveContext];
But that didn't work. WHat should I be calling?

Comment: This question is not about Xcode, so I've removed the tag.

Comment: About your problem, you need some sort of mechanism to persist the data on the device. There are several available on iOS. What kind of information does your application deal with? Only notes? Something else?

Comment: There isnt just a some coding to save all the data?

Comment: It depends on the complexity of your app. If your data is simple, you can use `NSUserDefaults`, or the `writeToFile:atomically:` method of `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`. If it is complex (notes with relationships, many entities, etc.), you need to learn more powerful techniques, for example Core Data.

Comment: Here is where I got the project
https://github.com/ColinEberhardt/iOS-ClearStyle
Should I be using NSUserDefaults or no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can usual use something such as `NSUserDefaults` to save information. Or, you can go another route and save the information in a data structure and write that to a file. There are many easy ways of doing this. For instance, if you want to preserve a checked value, you could do the following:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setBool:YES forKey:"checked"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Very simple, and then can be queried across app exits, like so:

```
if( [defaults boolForKey:"checked"] ) {
    //do stuff here
}
```

Comment: How about    
    -(void)saveToUserDefaults:(NSString*)myString
{
 NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    
 if (standardUserDefaults) {
  [standardUserDefaults setObject:myString forKey:@"Prefs"];
  [standardUserDefaults synchronize];
 }
}

-(NSString*)retrieveFromUserDefaults
{
 NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 NSString *val = nil;
 
 if (standardUserDefaults)
  val = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"Prefs"];
 
 return val;
    }